# Find if Windows is OEM without WMI

Tags: c#, .net

It can be done using WMI.

But is there a simple way (similar to `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem`)?

EDIT: There are permission limitations on WMI. As far as I know `Is64BitOperatingSystem` is much "better" in this respect, and maybe others. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

I'm trying to make sure the code will always run, without throwing exceptions.

Comment: If it can be done using WMI then why not just use WMI? (This reminded me of [The curious pattern of pre-emptively rejecting the solution to your problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/06/10391383.aspx))

Comment: @Justin Because of [This member cannot be used by partially trusted code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67a77ef1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and others like it.

Comment: So your question is "Find if Windows is OEM from partially trusted code"?

Comment: @Justin Sort of. I'm trying to make sure the code will always run, without throwing exceptions. Permissions are an obvious example.

Comment: @Justin - No...The question is to "Find if Windows is OEM from fully trusted code" but I don't think thats possible.  I am not sure the point of determining Windows license is OEM or not.

Comment: Why is this not a real question?  @ispiro, you might want to look into Win32 GetVersionEx and OSVersionEx structure.  szCSDVersion string *might* have that info.  Not sure.

Comment: `szCSDVersion` will definitely *not* have this info. It indicates only the version of the service pack that is installed, nothing about whether it's an OEM copy or not. cc @bryan

Comment: I wasn't sure but I've seen posts like this one that had OEM in the Win95 string.  http://jesusnjim.com/programming/GetVersionEx.html

Comment: This windows dialog prints OEM and I was assuming it was calling GetVersionEx and returning that string:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/158238

Comment: @bryan If you'd posted that comment 15 years ago, my response might have been different. What you say may well be true for Windows 9x, but the world runs on NT now and has for quite some time. In the NT world, `szCSDVersion` returns only a string identifying the maximum applied service pack version.

Comment: @Cody - cool.  That's why it was a comment and I conditioned it with *might*.

Answer (score 4):

Well, first off, the `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem` is able to do its job without requiring any special permissions because it doesn't actually do any checks whatsoever. The 64-bit version of the .NET Framework is hard-coded to return true, and the 32-bit version to return false. Simple as that.

Things are going to be a bit more complicated for the information you wish to obtain, unfortunately.

You don't say how you're obtaining this information through WMI, but I assume that you're querying the `SerialNumber` property of the `Win32_OperatingSystem` class, then taking the information you already know about the format of Windows product IDs to determine whether the OS was installed using an OEM key. If there's an `OEM` as the second part of that key, then you return true, otherwise false.

Of course, that section of the key could also be numeric, with certain numeric values indicating an OEM key. For example, I remember that certain values in the 600s indicate OEM keys, but I couldn't tell you exactly which ones. Hopefully you have a master list of all of these (from where, I wonder?), and are checking against them as well. Otherwise, you'll get a number of false negatives.

Anyway, assuming that's your approach (and it's the only one I can think of), the question becomes "How can I obtain the Windows product ID without using WMI?"

You could try querying the registry for it, but this is a fragile approach. It's not documented to be in a certain location in the registry, so this is subject to change between Windows versions. On current versions, it's in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductId
```

To make this work, you'll also have to properly handle 32-bit vs 64-bit, and your application will require elevation—only administrators can muck about with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

As far as I know, this information is not otherwise exposed by the Win32 API. Certainly there is no `IsOEMVersion` function, and it's neither one of the members of the [`OSVERSIONINFOEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833.aspx) structure nor one of the flags used by the [`IsOS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773795.aspx) function.

There is, obviously, a reason that WMI exists. If it does what you want, then you should use it. There's nothing inherently "unsafe" about it. If the information you wish to query requires certain privileges to access, well then it does for a reason and you're not going to have much success in finding alternate routes of accessing it that bypass those security restrictions.

If it is absolutely necessary that you have partially-trusted code harness the vast power of WMI, you can create an intermediate fully-trusted assembly that exposes the necessary functionality, and then call that from the partially-trusted assembly.

But in this particular case, you should seriously question why you need or want this information. What difference does it make if it's an OEM version of the operating system? It behaves identically from your perspective (both as a user and as a developer). If you'd given us more information about what you are planning to use this information to accomplish, we might be able to give some better suggestions.

Comment: +1 - note that WMI is getting that info from somewhere :)  Sometimes it's simpler, faster and reliable to go Win32/Registry route.

Comment: I disagree... I mentioned that the registry was unreliable because you have to hardcode a location that might change, while WMI takes care of this for you. It's also not simpler, especially if you're using the .NET wrappers for WMI. And it doesn't solve the problems here, because you still need permissions. Only fully-trusted code is guaranteed to have the requisite permissions to read the registry, and then it could have just queried WMI. The only strike against WMI is that it might be slower than reading the registry directly. But if you cared about speed, you wouldn't be using .NET.

Comment: WMI also relies on a much higher stack of code and dependencies.  It relies on a service running (which believe it or not, some shops stop/disable for surface area, security, whatever).  I've been on products that are very serious about keeping dependencies and the stack to a minimum.  So there are cases where win32/registry is appropriate.  Also, in general, yes, registry entries can change but windows ones like that do not.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Yes, I'm using Win32_OperatingSystem SerialNumber. No, I didn't know that some OEM's don't have the "OEM" string. As you have surmised - the registry won't help because of permission limitations. Yes, there's nothing inherently "unsafe" about WMI - however, sometimes the same information can be acquired with less privileges. Thanks again.